Changing the color of the dropdown select icon when hovering over the icon in Material UI
I’m working on a React.js project using Material UI. I want to change the color of the dropdown select icon when I hover over it. However, I only want the icon to change color only when I hover over the select icon, and not the entire select component.
The current code is
import ExpandMore from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";

<Select
              className="selectField"
              variant="standard"
              fullWidth
              IconComponent={ExpandMore}
/>

I tried using the &:hover attribute, but it changes the color of the entire select box when I hover over it.
I also tried using inspect element to change the z-index of the icon.
Lastly, I also tried passing the color change as a prop, but this caused the select icon to lose its functionality and become unclickable.
//tsx file
IconComponent={(iconProps) => (
                <ExpandMore {...iconProps} className="MuiSelect-icon" />
              )}
//CSS file
  .MuiSelect-icon {
    color: #121212 !important;
    // pointer-events: visiblePainted;
    &:hover {
      color: #0645c5;
    }
  }


Are you try this solution I have shared with pseudo element

 .MuiSelect-icon {
   color: #121212 !important;
   // just add quotations like below it works for me
   '&:hover': {
     color: '#0645c5';
   }
 }

